# What is the best namespace for a binary operator?

Tags: c++, c++11, argument-dependent-lookup

For elegance, encapsulation and to exploit ADL ([Argument Dependent Lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup)) is common to define a function inside the namespace of the function argument.

Suppose I have two libraries in different namespace. There are three cases 1) one is part of a library I control and the other is third party (for example Boost), or 2) I control both, or 3) I control none (just writing "glue" code).

I have something like this,

```
namespace ns_A{
   struct A{...}; // something that looks like iostream
}
namespace ns_B{
   struct B{...};
}
```

I want to "stream" B in to A, what is the best option

```
namespace ???{ // what is more correct ns_A, or ns_B?
   A& operator<<(A& a, B const& b){...} 
}
```

or should I put it in both namespaces?

```
namespace ns_B{
   A& operator<<(A& a, B const& b){...} 
}
namespace ns_A{
   using ns_B::operator<<;
}
```

**Which is the best namespace to define a binary function like this?**

(Does C++11's namespace inline change any recommendation?)

(I use the example `operator<<` because, other things being equal it *seems* intuitively be better to prefer `namespace ns_B`.)

---

**EDIT:** this is the most complete guide and reference I could find on real use of namespaces 
https://www.google.com/amp/s/akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2016/01/16/a-customizable-framework/amp/

Comment: Don't fiddle with namespace that you do not control.

Comment: @Walter, apparently that recommendation is good for Std. But apparently good solutions actually fiddle with other's namespaces https://www.google.com/amp/s/akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2016/01/16/a-customizable-framework/amp/

Answer (score 5):

In case 1, it is easy: put it in the `namespace` that you control.

In case 2, it's up to your choice: whatever appears more logical. In your example case, I would prefer `ns_B`.

The only tricky situation is 3. You shouldn't really add to either `namespace`. If you want the new 'glue' functionality as part of your own third `namespace mine`, then naturally put it in there and any use of that functionality within `mine` will be automatically resolved. Naturally, this will not envoke ADL, but there is no need for it, since all you want is to use the new functionality within `mine`, not somewhere else.

Answer (score 4):

You can put your operator in either namespace and it will work. As a best practice, put it in the namespace that belongs to your code.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion: Don't use any of the namespaces. Code in `ns_A` is not aware, in itself, of the existence of anything in `ns_A` - it doesn't depend on it; so code regarding both `ns_B` and `ns_A` constructs does not belong in `ns_A`. The same is true for `ns_B`, by symmetry.

Your `operator<<` should be in the "least common namespace" among `ns_A` and `ns_B`, which is probably no namespace (but if `ns_A` is `ns1::ns2` and `ns_B` is `ns1::ns3` then use `ns1`).

Forcing code into a namespace it does not clearly belong in is, in my opinion, not elegant and breaks encapsulation, conceptually. As for ADL, I think you should not expect more than what the "least common namespace" of `ns_A` and `ns_B` gives you.

Comment: Bold recommendation certainly. This is an option to consider. The best part, the good things about ADL will keep working.